# No provider for $injector- In AngularJs + Angular 8 Hybrid application unit test case

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-hybrid

I am writing the unit test cases for the Angular 8 app. This is the hybrid application with AngularJs + Angular 8.

I'm getting following error:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[TestService -> $injector]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TestService -> $injector]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for $injector!
```

I'm not sure, how to mock $injector class. I tried the mock the `TestService`, I won't be able to cover some integration test cases in that scenario.

Any help in mocking $injector class would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mock object for $injector . I had faced a similar issue for $rootscope in my project where I provided an empty object for $rootscope using Angular provider :

```
    {provide: '$rootScope',useValue : {}}

This provider will be part of TestBed configuration like this :

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [],
          imports: [],
          providers : [{provide: '$rootScope',useValue : {}}]
        })
          .compileComponents();
      }));
```

You can provide any dummy value as per your requirement instead of the empty object for useValue.

Answer (score -1):

Its a syntax error, TestService import right component/module.
for more information "https://angular.io/start"

Comment: Dude, I'm trying to mock the $injector of AngularJS in Angular 8 unit test.

Comment: check this link it will help "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54651220/no-provider-for-injector-in-angular-testing"